# Checking # of times word occurs in text file (Python)

Tags: python, string

Im working in python trying to find the # of times an input is found inside of a text file, but the output always displays the letter count of the text file in place of how many times a word occurs in the file. I am unsure as to what would cause it to output the letter count instead.

```
def occurrenceChecker(query):
    wordInFile = 0 
    file = open("C:\Users\Noah\Desktop\1000words.txt") 
    documentText = file.read

    for query in documentText():
        wordInFile +=1
    
    if wordInFile == 0:
        print("Your argument occurred " + str(wordInFile) + " times, none.")
    if wordInFile >= 1 and wordInFile <= 5:
        print("Your argument occurred " + str(wordInFile) + " times, low.")
    if wordInFile >= 6 and wordInFile <= 10:
        print("Your argument occurred " + str(wordInFile) + " times, medium.")
    if wordInFile >=11:
        print("Your argument occurred " + str(wordInFile) + " times, high.")
```

Output:

```
Please enter an argument that you are searching for in the file: stuck
Your argument occurred 4875 times, high.
Your argument occurred 4875 times, high.
```

Comment: first you could use `print()` to see what you have in variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling a function when you don't want to be and not calling a function when you do want to be.

Change `for query in documentText():` to `for query in document_text:`

Change `document_text = file.read` to `document_text = file.read()`

```
def occurrenceChecker(query):
    word_in_file = 0 
    file = open("C:\Users\Noah\Desktop\1000words.txt") 
    document_text = file.read()

    for query in document_text:
        word_in_file +=1
    
    if word_in_file == 0:
        print("Your argument occurred " + str(word_in_file) + " times, none.")
    if 1 <= word_in_file <= 5:
        print("Your argument occurred " + str(word_in_file) + " times, low.")
    if 6 <= word_in_file <= 10:
        print("Your argument occurred " + str(word_in_file) + " times, medium.")
    if word_in_file>=11:
        print("Your argument occurred " + str(word_in_file) + " times, high.")
```

Now that you have that, we now need to address the incrementing issue.
Instead of

```
for query in document_text:
        word_in_file +=1
```

You actually want to do something like this:

```
occurrences = document_text.count(query)
```

And then of course you should have a `main()` and call your function in said `main()`

```
def main():
    occurrenceChecker(input())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Source: https://pythonexamples.org/python-count-occurrences-of-word-in-text-file/

Comment: Oh my god you're a lifesaver. I was really stuck on the aspect of counting the word in the file and I thought I could have just used a for loop but I guess not. Thanks so much for the help your fix was a success!

Comment: @NoahPreston Oh don't get me wrong you totally *Can* use a for loop... But as is always the case in programming, someone - or in this case, lots of someones - has already had this problem before you and come up with a better (or at least less hacky) way to do it easier.

Comment: Now you couldn't do it like you tried to, and the reason is *very* simple. When you say: `for query in document_text:` you are saying for each item in document_text (that would be as we humans call a "word"), `word_in_file += 1` and that's true, that's how many words there are. Your problem is that you are defining that `each item` as `query`

Comment: A way to better understand what I am saying is to throw a `print(query)` in the `for query in document_text:` loop. You will quickly see you are *not* printing the parameter of occurrenceChecker - named `query` but rather are printing the items that document_text is made up of, just like you told it to - `for each part, print part` for query, print query. `query` in that case is just the next item that makes up the document - the next word

Comment: The way to do what you wanted - with a loop - would be: `for word in document_text: if word = query: word_in_file += 1`